# problema con $(document).on en jquery?

Tags: jquery

tengo el siguiente código :

```
$(document).on('focus', '.albaran', function () {
    console.log($(this).data('error'));
     if ($(this).data('error') == 1) {
       $(this).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'El campo no puede estar vacio' });
     } else if ($(this).data('error') == 2) {
       $(this).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'focus', 'title': 'El campo no es numerico' });
     }
);
```

Quisiera hacer esto para otras clases, Algo así

```
$(document).on('focus', '.albaran .Pais .Ruta', function ()
```

Lo hago de esa forma pero no me funciona, hay una forma de poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('focus', '.albaran, .Pais, .Ruta', function ()
```

Que te sirva.

Saludos

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="one">Prueba 1</p>
<p class="two">Prueba 2</p>
<p class="three">Prueba 3</p>
<p class="four">Prueba 4</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.one, .two, .three, .four',function(){
  alert($(this).text());
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separa los espacios en blanco en la expresion `'.albaran .Pais .Ruta'` por comas:

`'.albaran, .Pais, .Ruta'`

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro un ejemplo mostrando código acorde con jQuery 3.

- Desde jQuery 3 `document.ready` es [deprecated](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function), así que se recomienda usar: `$(function() { ...`
- Se puede escuchar `$(".albaran, .ruta, .pais").click(function(){` sin tener que hacer referencia a `$document`
- Si por algún motivo quieres mostrar los contenidos de las tres clases, puedes escuchar un `div` identificado por un `id`. Si no te interesa de esa forma, puedes eliminar esta parte del código: `$("div#test").on("click", function() ...`

```js
$(function() 
{ //Desde jQuery 3 document.ready es deprecated


    //Escuchar por clases
    $(".albaran, .ruta, .pais").click(function()
    {
        alert($(this).text());
    });

    //Escuchar por bloque
    $("div#test").on("click", function() 
    {
        alert($(this).text());
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <p class="albaran">ALB123</p>
    <p class="pais">España</p>
    <p class="ruta">A4</p>
</div>
```